# Shortest path in Directed Acyclic Graph with small degree

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a weighted directed acyclic graph on `n` vertices such that each vertex has indegree at most `5` and outdegree at most `5`. The nodes `0, 1, ..., n - 1` are oriented like this

`0   1   2   3   4`

`5   6   7   8   9`

`10  11  12  13  14`

`...`

`n-5 n-4 n-3 n-2 n-1`

Edges can only be from a node in a row to some node in the next row.

We'll be given `q` queries, asking the shortest path length from `u` to `v`. Here `n` can be upto `10^5` and `q` upto `10^4`. Weights are all positive integers.

Can we do better than `O(nq)` dynamic programming (which clearly doesn't work here)?

Comment: Please be more specific about the graph layout. Does every row consist out of exactly 5 nodes, which means that `n` is a multiple of 5?

Comment: Yes every row consists of 5 nodes, except possibly the last row. That row contains the remaining <= 5 nodes.

Comment: Why with dynamic programming the complexity time is `O(n^2)`? I think it's `O(e)` with `e` the number of edges of the graph. Like each node can at most have `5` edges, the complexity would be `O(5n) = O(n)`.

Comment: O(n) per query so it's O(nq) actually. Sorry.

Comment: If the graph is directed and edges can only be from one row to the next one and not the previous one. Don't you just have to determined if two nodes are connected? Then the distance will be floor(v/5) - floor(u/5).

Comment: The graph is weighted.

Comment: My bad, I read to fast, sorry.

Comment: You have then lineal time per query, which is really good. Why do you think you can do it better? If you have any guess tell us

Comment: lineal time per query with Theta(n) queries is actually worse than O(n^2) preprocessing to get all the shortest paths and then O(1) queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems too good to be true, sorry if it's not... You can get `O(n)` (*EDIT*: `O(n^(4/3))`) preprocessing and O(1) query.

I'm considering that you know how to compute all the shortest distances between all the nodes in the graph in time `O(n^2)`. (which is indeed possible, you seem to know that)

Divide your graph in `k` blocks, each containing `n/(5*k)` rows. (the blocks should start and finish on complete rows, and two consecutive ones overlap on their respective first and last row)

Compute the shortest path between all nodes (and in particular the first and last row) in each block: `O((n/k)^2)`.

Then you can consider the reduced graph containing only the nodes at the boundary between two blocks, with edges value equal to the shortest path between them that you've just computed.This reduced graph is of size `O(k)`.
Compute all the shortest paths in that graph in time `O(k^2)`.

Total preprocessing time: `O((n/k)^2 + k^2)`. Take `k=sqrt(n)`, you get `O(n)` preprocessing.

The query time is then `O(1)`: take the 5 nodes at the end of u's block, the 5 at the start of v's block (if the blocks are different), you just need to compare the 25 possibilities for u->v

**EDIT**

Of course it's false. You actually have k blocks for which to compute the shortest paths, so the total complexity for that step is `O(k*(n/k)^2)`. so the total is `O(n^2/k + k^2)`, and the best choice for k is `k=n^(2/3)`, which gives a total complexity of preprocessing of `O(n^(4/3))` and total queries `O(q)`

Comment: Maybe you can still improve this by applying this method recursively

Comment: To compute all shortest distances in O(n^2): just iterate through the graph in the usual order. On each node, store the distance from each previous one. When you reach a new node x, for each other node before it, just compare the 5 possibilities given by x's 5 possible predecessors. That's O(n) for each x, O(n^2) in total.

Comment: this is a nice solution - just to make sure there is no confusion about the actual complexity, instead of O(n^4/3) maybe you should write it like O(n ^ (4/3)).